# Infinite Union of open/ closed interval

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

Can you prove that 
$$
[a,b] = \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} \bigg(a-\frac{1}{n}, b\bigg]
$$
And that 
$$
(a,b] = \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} \bigg(a+\frac{1}{n}, b\bigg]
$$

I would like a general rule to demonstrate this, because it comes up very often.

Comment: @ÁngelMarioGallegos yes!

Comment: I made an edit. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Practicize $A=B\iff \forall x[x\in A\iff x\in B]$

Comment: @ΘΣΦGenSan yes, thanks !

Comment: I have a deja vu, I think that this question was asked a few days ago.

Answer (score 2):

**Problem 1.** Prove that 
$$
[a,b] = \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} \bigg(a-\frac{1}{n}, b\bigg].
$$
**Proof.**

$(i)$ For each $n\in\Bbb N$, we have $a-\frac{1}{n}<a$ and so for each $n\in\Bbb N$, we get $[a,b]\subset \bigg(a-\frac{1}{n}, b\bigg]$ and so, $$[a,b] \subset\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} \bigg(a-\frac{1}{n}, b\bigg].$$

$(ii)$ Let $$x\in \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} \bigg(a-\frac{1}{n}, b\bigg].$$ Then $a-\frac{1}{n}<x\leq b$ for all $n\in\Bbb N$, that is, $a-x<\frac{1}{n}$ for all $n\in\Bbb N$. Thus, we must have $a\leq x$ (hope you can prove it). Hence, $x\in [a,b]$. Thus, 
$$\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} \bigg(a-\frac{1}{n}, b\bigg]\subset [a,b].$$ Combining $(i)$ and $(ii)$, equality follows and this proves problem 1.

---

**Problem 2.** Prove that
$$
(a,b] = \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} \bigg(a+\frac{1}{n}, b\bigg].
$$
**Proof.**

$(i)$ For each $n\in\Bbb N$, $a<a+\frac{1}{n}$ and so for each $n\in\Bbb N$, we get $\bigg(a+\frac{1}{n}, b\bigg]\subset (a,b]$. Hence,
$$
\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} \bigg(a+\frac{1}{n}, b\bigg]\subset(a,b].
$$

$(ii)$ Let $x\in (a,b]$. Then $a<x\leq b$. Since $x-a>0$, we can find $m\in\Bbb N$ such that $\frac{1}{m}<x-a$, that is, $a+\frac{1}{m}<x\leq b$. Hence, $x\in \bigg(a+\frac{1}{m}, b\bigg]$ for some $m\in\Bbb N$. Thus,
$$x\in \bigg(a+\frac{1}{m}, b\bigg]\subset \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} \bigg(a+\frac{1}{n}, b\bigg].$$ Hence,
 $$(a,b]\subset\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} \bigg(a+\frac{1}{n}, b\bigg].$$
Combining $(i)$ and $(ii)$, equality follows.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

For the first $$[a,b]\subseteq\left]a-\tfrac1n,b\right]\qquad \text{for any integer }n>0$$
so
$$[a,b]\subseteq\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}\left]a-\tfrac1n,b \right]$$
Now, let $x\in\mathbb{R}\backslash\left[a,b\right]$, if $x$ is not greater than $b$ then $x<a$, so for $N\ge\frac1{a-x}$ we have $x\notin\left]a-\frac1N,b\right]$, so $x\notin\mathbb{R}\backslash\bigcap_{n=0}^{\infty}\left]a-\frac1n,b\right]$ which means
$$\mathbb{R}\backslash\left[a,b\right]\subseteq\mathbb{R}\backslash\bigcap_{n=0}^{\infty}\left]a-\tfrac1n,b\right]$$
Then $$\bigcap_{n=0}^{\infty}\left]a-\tfrac1n,b\right]\subseteq \left[a,b\right]$$